# Laravel query builder with count of dependencies

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, lumen

I've got a problem with building query with Laravel (Lumen).
This is my code:

```
$user = User::where('name', $name)
        ->with(['pages' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->with(['posts'])
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->take(4);
        }])
        ->first();
```

I would like to add to the response count of pages and posts so I want the response to have two more extra fields like:

```
...
pages_count: 5,
posts_count: 25
...
```

How can I do it?

Adding ->count() to queries doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) like so:

```
User::where('name', $name)
    ->withCount('pages')
    ->with(['pages' => function($query){
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->withCount('posts')
            ->with('posts')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->take(4);
    }])
    ->first();
```